# What parameters does the copy method take in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have this interface and I want it to be able to use copy method just like how data class does. So I define abstract copy method as this.

```
interface Fizzbuzz {
  fun clone(params: WhatShouldBeDefinedHere?): Fizzbuzz
}
```

so the implementation would be

```
data class Foobar(...): Fizzbuzz {
  override fun clone(...): Fizzbuzz {
    return this.copy(...)
  }
}
```

but what kind of parameters would it take?

Comment: What do u mean "what kind of parameters" ? Could u give more detail?

Answer (score 1):

It takes parameters as whatever `data class` has as fields. For example if you had following data class:

```kotlin
data class FooBar(field1: String, field2: Int)
```

The method have the signature:

```kotlin
fun copy(field1: String = this.field1, field2: Int = this.field2)
```

Reference: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying